# when using iText, how to SetPdfVersion in C#?

Tags: c#, itext

The document in the official site shows that the SetPdfVersion  is as below:

```
public void setPdfVersion(char version)
```

It's java version.So I can call it like below:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
```

So when I want to use it in C#, I found that the setPdfVersion's signature is

```
 public virtual void SetPdfVersion(PdfName version);
```

There's no document about this function in C#, So how can I do it with c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7;
```

Where `writer` is an instance of `PdfWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the reason.
In java the setXXX or getXXX is equivalent to the property in C#.

So we can find a property PdfVersion in PdfWriter in C#.